# SQL queries using SQL Injections do not work as I think they should

Tags: authentication, web-application, php, sql-injection, mysql

I am trying to learn about SQL Injections. I have created a login form using PHP (I am quite new to PHP) as backend scripting language and MySQL as DBMS. Last day I asked a question about SQL Injections: 
[SQL Injection not working when I think it should](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/129475/sql-injection-not-working-when-i-think-it-should), and it solved me some doubts, but now I have new doubts:

What I am trying to achieve is to bypass the login form that I have created, using SQL Injections. This is the script to check if the entered username and password belong to a user already registered (stored in the DB).

```
$email = $_POST['u_email'];
$password = $_POST['u_password'];

$query = "SELECT * FROM User WHERE EMAIL='$email' AND PASSWORD='$password'";
$result = $mysqli->query($query);
$counter = mysqli_num_rows($result);

echo "Counter: " . $counter . '<br>';
echo "Query: " . $query;
if($counter == 1)//Correct Login
```

I have to say that **I am really confused about the result gotten when running the queries.** I have created the following 3 examples where in each of them I insert different username and password values in the login form and the true is that I do not understand the gotten result of any of the examples, I think the results should be different.

**1 Example:** (abc@gmail.com is an existing email in the User table)

```
Input
Username: abc@gmail.com' OR '1'='1/*
Password: */

Output
Counter: 1
Query: SELECT * FROM User WHERE EMAIL='abc@gmail.com' OR '1'='1/*' AND PASSWORD='*/'
```

**Should not the $counter variable value be 30 (30 is the number of registered users in the User table)?**

When I run the following query  in the MySQL CLI:

```
SELECT * FROM User WHERE EMAIL='abc@gmail.com' OR '1'='1'
```

I get 30 rows, so **why $counter value is 1 and not 30?**

**2 Example:**  (xxx is NOT an existing email in the User table)

```
Input
Username: xxx' OR '1'='1/*
Password: */

Output
Counter: 0
Query: SELECT * FROM User WHERE EMAIL='xxx' OR '1'='1/*' AND PASSWORD='*/'
```

**Should not the $counter variable value be 30 (30 is the number of registered users in the User table)?**

When I run the following query  in the MySQL CLI:

```
SELECT * FROM User WHERE EMAIL='xxx' OR '1'='1'
```

I get 30 rows, so **why $counter value is 0 and not 30?**

**3 Example:** (abc@gmail.com is an existing email in the User table)

```
Input
Username: abc@gmail.com/*
Password: */

Output
Counter: 0
Query: SELECT * FROM User WHERE EMAIL='abc@gmail.com/*' AND PASSWORD='*/'
```

**Should not the $counter variable value be 1?**

When I run the following query  in the MySQL CLI:

```
SELECT * FROM User WHERE EMAIL='xxx' OR '1'='1'
```

I get 1 row, so **why $counter value is 0 and not 1?**

Comment: I am pretty sure that '/*' does *not* start a comment. Comments can only be started outside of quotes.

Comment: I think it does http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/comments.html

Comment: There is nothing at that page that suggests that you can start a comment from within quotes.  I know for a fact that neither the SQL standard nor other major DBMSs allow this and I sincerely doubt that MySQL does either.  Plus that would exactly explain everyone of your results.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Example 1 & 2

This is because your query is applying this clause:

```
'1'='1/*'
```

If you have a comment character inside of your quotes the comment is not respected by the query parser, you would have to exit the quoted context first.

1 is returned as count because that's how many users have that email address.

Try this instead for example 1 (the same technique will apply to the others):

```
Username: abc@gmail.com' OR '1'='1'; --
Password: Whatever
```

This should make the query

```
SELECT * FROM User WHERE EMAIL='abc@gmail.com' OR '1'='1'; -- ' AND PASSWORD='Whatever'
```

### Example 3

I'm guessing that you do not have a user with the email address `abc@gmail.com/*` set? Again, because of the quotes, it will be querying `abc@gmail.com/*` and not `abc@gmail.com`.

Comment: Answer updated.

Comment: It makes sense but I do not know why, if I insert Username: abc@gmail.com' OR '1'='1'; -- , It is like the query is wrong because it prints Counter: and no number. If I run the query in the MySQL CLI and write --whatever it is not accepted as a comment. Instead if I write --[whitespace]whatever it works. The problem is that If I write in the form --[whitespace] it does not work. :(

Comment: Sorry, I'd missed the whitespace from my first edit. Now updated.